# Prove the set of functions $T$ is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that $$T=\{t(x)|t(x)=a(x^2-1)+b\ln x+c\cot x\}$$ is a vector space.

My attempt:
To prove a vector space is to prove for $x_1,x_2\in T$, $x_1+x_2\in T$. So I calculated $$t(x_1)+t(x_2)=a({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2-2)+b \ln x_1x_2+c(\cot x_1+\cot x_2)$$ But clearly it is not in T. Where did I miss?

Comment: You need to compute $(t_1+t_2)(x)$, not $t(x_1)+t(x_2)$!

Comment: Objects in $T$ are functions, say $f$ and $g$, then to be closed under addition, you need to show that $f+g$ is in $T$ as well. What you have done is taken inputs to the functions as the objects of $T$, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther must be $x_1= x_2=x$ and $$t_1(x)= a_1(x^2-1)+b_1\ln x  +c_1\cot x$$ $$t_2(x)= a_2(x^2-1)+b_2\ln x  +c_2\cot x$$ so

$$t_1(x)+t_2(x)= \underbrace{(a_1+a_2)}_{a}(x^2-1)+\underbrace{(b_1+b_2)}_{b}\ln x  +\underbrace{(c_1+c_2)}_{c}\cot x$$